# How to navigate to other page after click on button in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am an beginner in react native.I want to display home page after logged in.I have install react-navigator using npm install and I have tried below code.

But I am getting below error, I tried to solve this. Still I have the error.

[image]

In App.js

```
//This is an example code for Bottom Navigation//
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
//import all the basic component we have used
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 50, fontSize: 25 }}>Setting!</Text>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Two')}>
            <Text>Go to Home Tab</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Two')}>
            <Text>Open Detail Screen</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Two')}>
            <Text>Open Profile Screen</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 16,
  },
});
```

Can anyone assist me to solve this?

Comment: Where is the stack Navigator code??

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as following:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Login Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

on App.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import { HomeScreen, LoginScreen } from '..'// should set the proper path.
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Home: HomeScreen
});

const App = () => {
  return <AppNavigator />;
}
export default App;
```